# getElementsByClassName iterating through array

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementsbyclassname

I'm learning Javascript and I can't seem to figure out why the following code does not work.  It will change the background of the first paragraph, but not the second one.  When I check the console, it looks like the access variable is only returning one item to the array.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

HTML

```
<p class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
<p class = "blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
```

CSS:

```
.blue{
background: blue;
}
.orange{
background:orange;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var access = document.getElementsByClassName("blue");
for(var i = 0; i<access.length; i++){
access[i].className = "orange";
}
```

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll('.blue')` instead. It doesn't return a live node list like `getElementsByClassName` does and you won't get that issue.

Answer (score 6):

You're getting a live nodeList, meaning the collection will update as the DOM changes.

When you change the classname inside the loop, one element no longer matches the selector `.blue` and the length is suddenly `1` and not `2`, so the loop ends before it reaches the second element.

When iterating over live nodeLists, one should generally iterate in reverse

```
var access = document.getElementsByClassName("blue");

for (var i = access.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    access[i].className = "orange";
}
```

Or you could you use a method that gets you a non-live nodeList instead, like `document.querySelectorAll('.blue')`

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand this.  I got it working and tried your other suggestion, using querySelectorAll('.blue').  I can't get it to work:       var access2 = document.querySelectorAll(".blue");
for(var i = 0; i<access2.length; i++){
access2[i].className = ".orange";
  }

Comment: @trustIsEarned - remove the period, it should be `access2[i].className = "orange"`